# How to parse XKB list in Python 3?

Tags: python

I need to parse XKB file located in /[usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/debian/wheezy/main/all/xkb-data/2.5.1-3/file/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst) (on Linux) and split result into several lits, e.g.

`layouts = [] variants = [] options = []`

I found an "example" of how to do it in C++ ([LXQt Config](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-config/blob/master/lxqt-config-input/keyboardlayoutconfig.cpp)), but I can't get it to work in Python. Can someone help me?

I tried this code, but lists are empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

layouts = []
options = []
variants = []

with open('/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    line = line.strip()

    if line.startswith('! layout'):
        layouts.append(line[1:])
    elif line.startswith('! option'):
        options.append(line[1:])
    elif line.startswith('! variant'):
        variants.append(line)

print('Layouts:')
print(layouts)
print()
print('Options:')
print(options)
print()
print('Variants:')
print(variants)
```

Comment: You tagged this as C++, but you are using python.  Unless you are willing to take that C++ code, make it a library, and call it from python, the C++ tag is really not relevant.  Maybe that's the route you should take, and that is to make the C++ "exportable", and just have python call those functions to get the results.  Trying to do line-by-line translations from C++ to python, rarely, if ever, works out correctly.

Comment: If you want to parse with Python, do not use C++ as a guideline. Very different languages with very different guiding idioms. The odds of a successful translation are low, and if you do succeed, the program will not be as good as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple text file, and the first column is always one word, so you can use "split" to parse it.  Note that I've used dictionaries here, so you end up with something you can use to look up the mappings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

layouts = {}
options = {}
variants = {}
current = None

with open('/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst') as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line) < 2:
            continue
        one, two = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)
        if one == '!':
            if two == 'layout':
                current = layouts
            elif two == 'option':
                current = options
            elif two == 'variant':
                current = variants
        elif current is not None:
            current[one] = two

print('Layouts:')
print(layouts)
print()
print('Options:')
print(options)
print()
print('Variants:')
print(variants)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I need! One question: is there a way to filter 'options' by keyword? This list contains many unneded key/values, I only want the ones that start with 'grp:'

Comment: Of course there is.  It's just a normal Python dictionary.  You can enumerate through the dictionary using `options.items()` and only keep those with the names you like.